# Manhwa where transmigrated siblings are engaged to each other

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I didn't read much before the translators dropped it, but a brother and sister are transmigrated into the same world, where the people they possessed are engaged to each other and now they have to figure out how to break off the engagement. Also, I think the female lead ends up liking this dark haired (dark skinned?) knight. Does anyone know the name of this one?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Stop This Marriage!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nqzjvzj/stop-this-marriage)***...?

> After getting in an unfortunate accident, the twins transmigrated to another world together. The elder sister possessed the body of Princess Liliana, and the younger brother went into the body of Arvid, the 2nd Prince of the Revoluta Empire. But the two were engaged and their wedding is only two months away. How will the two stop this marriage?!

The plot summary matches your description, and the sister is attracted to a guy with dark hair.

[image] [image]